# Could this code be causing a memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, uwp

My app is leaking about 6MB of RAM every time I navigate to or from a page and I think this is what the cause is:

I've got the following class:

```
public class JSONclasses
{
     public class RootObject
     {
         public ReleaseDates release_dates { get; set; }
         public int id { get; set; }
         public List<Result> results { get; set; }
     }
     //Another few hundred variables
}
```

And am using it in the following way on my pages:

```
using static TMDBclient.JSONclasses;
namespace TMDBclient
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : AltPage
    {
        public string defaultbackdrop;
        public string defaultposter;
        public int budget;
        public long revenue;
        //A copy of all the variables from the JSONclasses that I need

        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string result = await SetData();
            myTextBlock.Text = defaultbackdrop;
            //Continue setting all the data to the UI and doing various operations on it.
        }

        public async Task<string> GetMovieData(string id)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
                            defaultbackdrop = root.BackdropURL;
                            id = root.id;
                            //Continue setting all the variables in the same manner.
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To recap, I'm:

- Declaring JSONclasses as a static class
- Setting tons of variables
- Using those variables in my UI and performing various operations on them.

On another note, I've set NavigationCacheMode to Disabled, so it shouldn't be saving the entire page in memory.
Do you reckon this is what's leaking all that precious memory? I can tell this is particularly badly optimized code, and a few of you probably threw up a little inside your mouths reading it, but how can I fix it?

According to visual studio, there's definitely some [image: leakage going on.] And that's only by going back and forth to the same page a few dozen times.

Also, I've used ReSharper dotMemory to diagnose where the memory leak is coming from, and I'm 98% sure this is the source of the problem.

Comment: Are you certain that this is actually a memory leak?  Is the memory still 'leaked' after the garbage collector has run (which can run at any time unless you have explicitly invoked it)?

Comment: Please don't guess memory leak, can you profile using Dot memory profiler, that will provide a clear picture, of what's using suspected memory and whether it can be categorized as a leak

Comment: @MartinParkin , According to visual studio, there's definitely some leakage going on: http://i.imgur.com/SxA7lXT.png And that's only by going back and forth to the same page a few dozen times.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with additional information rather than providing it in comments.

Comment: I don't think it's the answer, but response.Content is IDisposable too, and you might as well dispose that too.  Then just as comment: there's no reason to use .Result there when you're in an async method; use await instead.  Also the way you're using the StreamReader you might as well instead do "string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()" and not use a stream at all.